# Can't Connect to MySQL database through PuTTY

Tags: mysql, connectivity, ssh

I have a database that runs on pythonanywhere.com, and am trying to connect Tableau to it, and need to set up an SSH Tunnel in order to do so.

The [directions](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/AccessingMySQLFromOutsidePythonAnywhere/#using-putty-on-windows) on pythonanywhere's website mention PuTTY, and many people on Tableau forums also use it, so this is what I'm going with.  I've been trying for about 2 weeks to get this working, but no luck.

So here's what happens:

1).  I enter `ssh.pythonanywhere.com` as the host connection on the main page:
[image]

2).  I then go to SSH --> Tunnels, and enter the following information: 
[image]

The information in the Destination field has the form `my-username.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com:3306`

Then I hit Open, and am prompted for my sign in credentials to Python Anywhere:

[image]

Then I go to Tableau and enter the following information:

[image]

In the password field I type in my database password.

The message that always comes up is:

```
[MySQL][ODBC 8.0(w) Driver]Access denied for user 'myusername'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Invalid username or password.
```

Now obviously, there's a natural response to this:  double check my password.

For now just take my word for it that I've double checked this several times and it is correct.

I've tried to find help on [PythonAnywhere's forums](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/14961/), and [Tableau's forums](https://community.tableau.com/thread/320453), but no solutions have been found.

Also:

I've tried switching out the port `127.0.0.1` with `localhost`, but this did not work.

I **have** connected to my database externally in a Jupyter Notebook using this same information, so I have some confirmation that this info has been used successfully.

I've tried connecting to MySQL Workbench using the same info and I get the same error message, which makes me think there's something about my database configuration which is not working, but I have no idea where to look.

**UPDATE:**

In my PuTTY Bash terminal the command `telnet 127.0.0.1 3306` returns the message:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

In my DOS terminal I get the following:

[image]

In my git BASH terminal I type in `netstat -an|grep 3306` and get:

[image]

**UPDATE 2:**

I was on codementor trying to get this resolved, and we had the following issue:

after signing in throuhg PuTTY, I entered the following command:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u jonathanbechtel -p
```

Which returned the following error message:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)
```

We also tried switching out `127.0.0.1` with `localhost` and got a different error message:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

To be honest I don't understand the significance of this, but was told by him that this is unusual and might signal some security settings on my account with PythonAnywhere.  I started [this forum message](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/15921/) on their forums to try and troubleshoot it.

Comment: Is access for `'myusername'@'localhost'` allowed though in your database? A connection via the SSH tunnel will be seen on the database server as a local one.

Comment: What @mustaccio said. If you can access via other means, then you need to check the authentication setup

Comment: @mustaccio - do you mean with the database on pythonanywhere?  I assume the answer is yes, since they list instructions on how to connect through PuTTy.

Comment: You shouldn't assume anything, if you intend to solve the problem instead of waiting for it to solve itself. Since you have other means to connect to the database, you can do so and check.

Comment: @mustaccio okay, I will double check, but I believe the answer is yes.

Comment: This is a very interesting post. I have a lot of possible tests to do but let's start from the beginning. If your putty tunnel is working you should be able to do this: "telnet 127.0.0.1 3306" if you see weird symbols and the word mysql and/or the mysql version then we are fine with this test. Otherwise, you will see: "Could not open connection to the host"... "Connection Failed".

Comment: @JesusUzcanga - Thanks.  Naive question -- where do I type this message?  In the PuTTY terminal after I've connected to Python Anywhere?

Comment: @JonathanBechtel, from your Windows CMD (DOS)... if disabled (Windows 8+) you can enable it following this link: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/38433.windows-10-enabling-telnet-client.aspx

Comment: @JesusUzcanga -- I believe we got the weird symbols, although I'm not sure if it's important the the PuTTY terminals and DOS terminals returned different results.

Answer (score 0):

If you are connecting on "localhost", then `GRANT ... TO user@localhost ...` applies.  "127.0.0.1" may be a synonym for "localhost".

If you are connecting via TCP/IP, then `GRANT ... TO user@'11.22.33.44' ...` applies.  (Replace with suitable IP or hostname or wildcard.)

It is OK to have both `GRANTs` in order to allow access either way.